# Building a project through C++ code in some other project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, project

I have a C++ solution built in MS Visual studio 2010  and it contains 2 projects. I would consider 1 out of it as my main project and it needs to get some output generated by the other project and then process it. Is there a way to do that in C++ ? I  mean, to build a project through C++ code in some other project ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of referencing the second project library in the main project and make use of Methods to exchange the data.

Comment: actually input to the first project should be given through the code of the second project. It is a must. and then the first project generates its output with the given input. and that output should be accessible in the code of second project. Is this possible through what you have mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to visualize your problem accurately, so pardon me.

As far as dependency between projects, you can try to use Makefile to manage the file dependencies. 
Or try to combine both projects and use function accordingly to pass parameters and return output.